# Why does $k reset itself back to zero every time through the loop?

Tags: php, increment

Why does $k reset itself back to zero every time through the loop?

```
$fruit = array ( “orange”, “apple”, “grape” ); 
$testvar = “no”; 

while ( $testvar != “yes” ) {  
    $k = 0; 
    if ($fruit[$k] == “apple” ) {    
        $testvar = “yes”; 
        echo “apple\n”; 

    } else { 
        echo “$fruit[$k] is not an apple\n”; 
    } 
    $k++; 
}
```

Comment: put `$k` before the while statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new variable each time the while loop runs. If you put `$k` before the while loop, then you will be able to increment it and get an accurate view of how many times the while loop has executed.

Note PHP only has function scope, so `$k` will still be available after this loop ends.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2):

You are initializing the variable `$k` inside the `while` loop.

```
while ( $testvar != “yes” ) {  
  $k = 0;
```

This will reset its value each time until the while condition fails. Initialize `$k` before `while` loop so that it's value is initialized only once, like

```
$k = 0; 
while ( $testvar != “yes” ) {
```

Comment: @Kolinio..Glad to help you.